# Convert UTC timestamp to PST in Python using standard libraries

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytz

I'm new to Python and trying to convert UTC timestamp to PST timestamp. I'm able to do it using python `pytz` in my local machine but on the server, I don't have `pytz` module installed.

Is there an alternative way to convert UTC time to PST time using python standard libraries without using `pytz` module? I'm using `python 2.7.5`

```
utc_time = "2021-03-10 07:55:00"
expected_pst_time = "2021-03-09 23:55:00"
```

Comment: You should install pytz on your server. In practice most Python programs require a number of external libraries, so you should get to a workflow that allows you to specify and install dependencies for your programs; unless you really like reinventing wheels. Timezone rules can be complex and change occasionally, which is why Python doesn't bundle them and externalises those into the pytz package, which can be updated independently of Python.

Comment: If you are new to Python you should not be investing time in learning Python 2. Those of us who still work in Python 2 do it because we have to support or convert legacy code.